# Xcode 10.3 where are the other iOS versioned simulators

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm using Xcode 10.3 and can't seem to figure out how to choose the iOS version of the simulator I want to test on. How can I run my app on an iOS 10 simulator? I used to have a long list and was able to choose between the iOS versions. Has it moved somewhere else?

I have the simulator downloaded, it just doesn't appear in Xcode's dropdown!

[image: Xcode screenshot simulator dropdown]

[image: Xcode screenshot simulator device settings]

Comment: What is your project's Deployment Target set to?

Comment: Ah that makes sense ... amazing, thank you so much!!!

Comment: Please "answer" the question and I'll accept it. Working on a demo app and did not think of setting the default target lower :S